# Acces HTML action from different URL's

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url, post

*this is my HTML code :

```
 <form method="POST" action="/sendMail">
```

is it possible to use this action with for example this url `: test/en/sendMail` ?

**How can i define in the html , that the action should listen to**

```
test/en/sendMail
test/de/sendMail
test/sendMail
```

without using this 3 times

```
<form method="POST" action="/en/sendMail">
<form method="POST" action="/de/sendMail">
<form method="POST" action="/sendMail">
```

Im using NodeJs by the way.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure but you can use `formaction` on your submit button as:

```
<form>
    [fields]
    <input type="submit" value="Submit to a" formaction="/submit/a">
    <input type="submit" value="submit to b" formaction="/submit/b">
</form>
```

More info on this available on link : http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html